# Is the exchange in Taiwan bank exchange office in Taoyuan airport same as the Taiwan bank inside the city?

Tags: money, exchange, taiwan

I want to pay the hotel soon in Taiwan. I have USD. I am not sure whether it is logical to pay with my bank card which I know has commission or change in airport since it is covid and the hotel wants us to pay while check in.

I see there is Taiwan bank exchange in Taoyuan airport but I am not sure about the rate whether same as website? Does anybody know the spread
https://rate.bot.com.tw/xrt?Lang=en-US

Comment: Even if the airport "bank exchange" uses the same rate, and the same spread as the downtown bank branches, the cost to the user may differ. Different fees, different commissions, and/or different rates, some or all of which are generally charged in airport locations, which are generally more expensive than downtown bank branches. There are too many possible inflection points for a single generality (like "spread" or "rate") to be useful.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica okay but, even if researching it online is not straightforward, surely it's an answerable question as to if the branch in the airport has the same fees, commissions, and rates as the downtown branch or not.

Comment: Countries are different. Easternare tough in these things! They have bank branch. Check it bank of taiwan taoyuan airport evenanother one mega bank

Comment: Ir is answeranle exactly based on experience. Anyway I willdecide whether I share my experience when  I reach or not!

Comment: I looked, and you are correct: the airport location does appear to be a branch of the Bank of Taiwan. But we still do not know if the Bank's airport branch changes money using the same rate/spread/commission/fee structure as the downtown branch. Let us know what you discover.

Comment: I did that sir. everything same except 30 NTD fee in airport.Perfect!!

Comment: And this 30 NTD is for any amount you change!